# Mac OS X pmset API

Tags: macos

Is there an API to query values displayed by `pmset`? I don't want to call `pmset` using an `NSTask` utility. Even though it seems doable but it's probably prone to a few errors across different versions of OS X (avoiding system utility output parsing).

I want to get values from `pmset -g assertionslog` if at all possible. Any pointers?

Comment: Here's the source for pmset. You can look it over, the docs online seem very old;  http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-97.5/pmset/pmset.c